# how to return 2 different types variables from a function in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, functional-programming

for example I have this 2 functions which one calls other function:

```
    private void show()
    {
       int labeledValue;
        //this is to show labeled letters 
        int[,] igmSize = labelImage(img);
        txtResult.Text = format(igmSize);
    }


    private int[,] labelImage(Bitmap image)
    {
        int[,] imgMatrix = new int[3, 4];
        int value;

        return imgMatrix;

    }
```

now I want to **retun** **imgMatrix** and **value** to first function at the sam time  how to do this plz any help?????

Comment: Are you assuming that your audience is only experts in OCR, and already understands the algorithm you're trying to implement? If not, then it seems this question leaves out a lot of detail. That said, if the label is supposed to be the same for each group of "connected" pixels (however you define that), then it seems you should increment the value after you have labeled the last pixel in the group of connected pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't; a function can only have one return value.

You *can* however get multiple values out of the function in three ways:

1. Return a `Tuple` object of the correct data types. This is a pretty hackish method, because the names for each value returned variable are "Value1, Value2" and so on.

   ```
   private Tuple<int[,], int> MyMethod() { ... }
   ```
2. Return a custom struct/class that holds your two objects. This is definitely the "best" way to do it.

   ```
   private ImageData MyMethod() { ... }
   ```
3. Create an `out` parameter that you fill.

   ```
   private int[,] MyMethod(out value) { ... }
   ```

I'd go with option (2), as it results in the most readable code. If `out` really makes sense (like it does for `TryParse` then (3) is also a good option. Only do (1) if you are happy with hard-to-read code.